# chain actions in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am new in vue and frontend, I need to get categories, then parse it to subcategories, what i am doing wrong? There is error 'is not a function'. Ho to do it in the correct way?

```
GET_CATEGORIES_FROM_API({commit}) {
            return axios('http://localhost:3000/categories',
                {
                    method: "GET"
                }).then((categories) => {
                    commit('SET_CATEGORIES_TO_STATE', categories.data)
                return categories;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                return error;
            })
        },
        GET_SUBCATEGORIES_FROM_CATEGORIES({commit}) {
                dispatch(this.GET_CATEGORIES_FROM_API()).then(categories => { // here is an error
                let subcategories = []
                for (let category in categories) {
                    for (let subcategory in category) {
                        subcategories.push(subcategory.name)
                    }
                }
                commit('SET_SUBCATEGORIES_TO_STATE', subcategories)
                return subcategories
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for dispatch is incorrect.

When dispatching, you use the same syntax as you do with commits. Simply pass a string reference to the name of the action like this

```
dispatch('MY_AWESOME_ACTION', ...optionalParams);
```